# Get sample of sound from stereo mix in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, windows-vista, audio

Is there a way in Windows using C# to record a sample of the stereo mix?

In other words, record all pings, beeps and music being played via any application? I've had a look at [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) which will record the microphone as it's source, but I can't figure out how to point it at Windows' stereo mix?

Or, if anyone knows, any pointers on how to target and record sound from a specific application? For this I'm only concerned with Vista or Windows 7, as both the aforementioned operating systems support mixing applications separately - so I wasn't sure if there was a way to tap into that.

I've looked at WINMM and COREDLL too, but I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

I think first you have to activate the stereo mix device in the control panel, then you should be able to record from it. Check this msdn thread: [How to record from 'Wave' or 'Stereo Mix' in Vista](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowspro-audiodevelopment/thread/e725bb7c-607c-410a-a495-9c92987a34c4).