# how to find the main speakers directshow audio device

Tags: c#, directshow, vlc, directshow.net, libvlc

I am capturing the desktop using VLC and DirectShow an I need to find the main speakers audio device in order to capture all the sound from the desktop, can this be done programmaticly ?
I am using C# in windows XP and 7

Comment: You need to pass VLC option `"--dshow-adev="<audio device name>"` in your libVLC coding. You can use VLC GUI capture device tab to find the name of your preferred audio device first and use the name in your coding. See [VLC command line help](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually cannot capture data from speakers. The real options are:

- audio capture from real audio input device, such as microphone
- audio capture from loop back device (provided that it is enabled)

Note that loopback capture is different in Vista+ and older systems, also previously discussed here:

- [Is it possible to record sound played on the sound card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241352/is-it-possible-to-record-sound-played-on-the-sound-card)
- [Get sample of sound from stereo mix in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855782/get-sample-of-sound-from-stereo-mix-in-windows)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993186/windows-7-any-audio-libraries-supporting-loopback-audio-capturing-in-c

Comment: loopback capture can only work if the sound card supports it ? assuming it does how can I detect the loopback device name ?

Comment: I am not sure if the input is marked specifically to indicated its loopback nature. It is possibly not and/or vendor specific.

Comment: is it possible to install a software loopback device ?

Comment: It should be supported by hardware, however note it's often (or typically?) disabled by default, so it might be there and you need to go to manually re-enable it.

Comment: @jacob you can use [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) as software loopback device. The demo version should be ok to test with.